# Retrieve Data in Parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have searched through a number of similar topics but have not found a solution as of yet. I am using Parse social and using the login files.

I get the following error:

"AnyObject?" is not convertible to 'String'

I am very new to Swift & Parse - I believe this is the correct method of retrieving data, so please correct me if I am wrong.

```
    var userObjectID = PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!


    var query = PFQuery(className:"User")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("\(userObjectID)") {
        (userInfo: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil && userInfo != nil {
            println(userInfo)
            let userScore = userInfo["level"] as! String
        } else {
            println(error)
        }
    }
```

Below is the database on Parse

[image]

Comment: https://twitter.com/AirspeedSwift/status/618451881250189312

Comment: Hey - sorry, I do not understand!

Comment: You should endeavor to understand that tweet before you continue writing Swift (and asking SO questions about it).

Comment: The problem is related to your `PFQuery` declaration: the default user tables name is not `"User"`, but `"_User"`, and I think it could be simplified as var query = PFUser.query()

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to unwrap the PFObject you receive:

```
let userScore = userInfo!["level"] as! String
```